# Что такое "Правило одного определения" (One definition rule)?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Что такое "Правило одного определения"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Правило одного определения (One definition rule или ODR) состоит из нескольких пунктов:

1. Единица трансляции не может содержать больше одного определения

   - переменной,
   - функции,
   - класса (в т.ч. `struct`),
   - перечисления,
   - шаблона.
2. Программа должна содержать ровно одно определение:

   - каждой не-`inline` функции,
   - каждой *ODR-использованной* переменной.

   Переменная считается "ODR-использованной" (odr-used), если она находится в потенциально вычисляемом выражении. Здесь есть некоторые исключения, но они не интересны в контексте самого правила одного определения.

   Под "программой" понимается ее исходный код, а также стандартная и пользовательские библиотеки. Компилятор не обязан выдавать какие-либо ошибки или предупреждения, если это правило нарушено.
   Все `inline` функции должны быть определены в каждой единице трансляции, где они ODR-использованы.
3. Единица трансляции должна содержать ровно одно определение класса, если он был использован таким образом, что его тип должен быть полным.
4. Программа может содержать несколько определений

   - класса,
   - перечисления,
   - `inline` функции с внешним связыванием,
   - шаблона класса,
   - шаблона не-`static` функции,
   - статического члена данных шаблона класса,
   - метода шаблона класса,
   - неполной специализации шаблона,

   если они находятся в разных единицах трансляции и удовлетворяют следующим условиям:

   - каждое определение должно состоять из одной и той же последовательности токенов;
   - имена, использованные в определении (в т.ч. использованные неявно), должны относиться к одним и тем же сущностям, или быть определены в самом определении;
   - в каждом определении сущности должны иметь одно и то же связывание;
   - если в определении есть вызов функции со значением аргумента по умолчанию, считается что токены значения вставляются в определение, и таким образом подпадают под правила, написанные выше;
   - если определение - это класс с неявно-определенным конструктором, он должен вызывать одни и те же конструкторы своих членов и базовых классов.

   Если это правило соблюдено, программа будет вести себя так, как будто в ней было только одно определение. В противном случае поведение программы не определено.

---

#### Примеры

ODR-использованные переменные

```
// Единица трансляции 1:        |     // Единица трансляции 2:
int x = 1;                      |     int x = 1;
int y = 1;                      |     int y = 1;
decltype(x) xx; // ОК, "x" использована в не-вычисляемом контексте.
int z = y; // нарушение ODR, "y" определена в двух единицах трансляции и ODR-использована.
```

Нарушение правила 4 (разные конструкторы базового класса)

```
// Единица трансляции 1:        |     // Единица трансляции 2:
struct X {                      |     struct X {
  X(int);                       |       X(int);
  X(int, int);                  |       X(int, int);
};                              |     };
                                |
X::X(int = 0) { }               |     X::X(int = 0, int = 0) { }
                                |
class D: public X { };          |     class D: public X { };
```

Неявно определенный конструктор `D::D()` нарушает ODR - в одном случае он использует `X(int)`, а в другом - `X(int, int)`

Более простой случай нарушения ODR:

```
// g.h                        
void f(float t);
inline void g() { f(1); }       
---------------------------------------------------------------------
// f_int.h
void f(int);
--------------------------------+------------------------------------
// main.cpp                     |    // f.cpp
#include "g.h"                  |    #include "f_int.h"
                                |    #include "g.h"
int main() {                    |
  g();                          |    void f(int) {}
}                               |    void f(float t) {}
```

Функция `g` вызывает разные функции `f` в разных единицах трансляции.
Это нарушает пункт "имена ... должны относиться к одним и тем же сущностям".

Comment: Интересно то, что последний (`более простой`) пример нарушает принцип ODR, но при этом большинство компиляторов не выдадут ошибку линковки (если, конечно, убрать `inline` перед `inline void g() { f(1); }`, то выдадут) и проект успешно соберется.
P.S. Ведь по идее тот пример почти удовлетворяет условиям ODR: `Программа может содержать несколько определений inline функции с внешним связыванием, если они находятся в разных единицах трансляции`, но реализация разная, так что пункт про `каждое определение должно состоять из одной и той же последовательности токенов` не выполняется.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive: Нарушение ODR — это UB и не требует диагностики, ЕМНИП.

Comment: @Abyx А разве это именно разные сущности, ведь там пару часов назад функция `f` была объявлена в виде `inline void f()..`, а не `void f()` как сейчас (как видимо подправили для наглядности), т.е. код должен был сериализоваться прямо в тело функции `g()` и таким образом последовательность токенов стала бы различаться, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Abyx Но на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y.aspx#Anchor_0) утверждается, что происходит подстановка копии тела inline функции (`The inline and __inline specifiers instruct the compiler to insert a copy of the function body into each place the function is called.`). Правда, судя по этой же статье, компилятор сам решает выгодно ли это в данном случае или нет, и основываясь на этом решении копирует/не копирует тело функции.

Comment: @Abyx Хм, но судя по всему ODR как раз и применяется на уровне единиц трансляции (т.е. *.obj-файлов на Windows и *.o-файлах в Unix), в которые как раз и сериализуется каждый файл исходного кода со своими хедерами. Или стоит смотреть на данное понятие, как на абстрактное, т.е. несколько отдаленно от самой реализации?

Comment: @Abyx Перечитал еще раз связанную с этим теорию - вы, все-таки, меня убедили :) P.S. Спасибо за поправку в терминологии, запомню :)