# Ошибка LNK2019 при вызове inline-функции

Tags: c++, функции, компоновщик, inline

Метод assing класса List объявлен в файле list.h

```
void assign(size_t, const value_type&);
```

При определении метода в файле list.cpp использую ключевое слово inline

```
inline void List::assign(size_t count, const value_type& val) {
   this->List::clear();
   this->List::List(count, val);
}
```

При вызове в main() данного метода получаю ошибку

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl List::assign(unsigned __int64,int const &)" (?assign@List@@QEAAX_KAEBH@Z) referenced in function main  list    C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\list\list\Source.obj   1
```

Вызов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "List.h"
#define typeof(a)cout<<typeid(a).name()<<endl;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    List ls(10,9);
    ls.assign(8, 8);
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: А list.cpp в проект добавлен?

Comment: Добавлен list.h

Comment: Программа не видит реализацию. Только объявление. Можно реализовывать в .h (обычно так делают), можно и в .cpp файл засунуть. Только тогда нужно его добавить в проект, чтобы компилировался, либо можно так `#include "List.cpp"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем Вы использует `inline` в файле реализации? Это неправильно, `inline` как раз нужен для того, чтобы размещать реализацию (определение) в заголовках. Размещать `inline` сущности в файлах реализации не имеет смысла в общем случае, да ещё и неверно в частных (включая Ваш). Уберите `inline` и всё у Вас заработает, либо перенесите реализацию в заголовок.

Релевантная цитата из стандарта (C++17:[basic.def.odr]p4):

> An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation
>   unit in which it is odr-used outside of a discarded statement

Comment: Проблему решило, благодарю. Но всё же остался вопрос. Разве inline не значит "Встраивать код функции в места ее вызова"? Или я ошибаюсь? Если не ошибаюсь, то какая разница, определять в .h или .cpp?

Comment: @Денис, `inline` значит разное, в том числе и то, что Вы написали, правда это всего лишь просьба, компилятор не обязан встроить вызов.  Теперь смотрите, Вы просите компилятор встраивать вызов `assign`, а сами прячете код этой функции в cpp файл, о котором компилятор в момент вызова ничего не знает (Вы ведь включаете только заголовок), как и что он может встроить?

Comment: на данный момент не рекомендуется помечать функции inline если только результат профилирования не показал обратного.

Comment: @Денис, вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418755/Что-такое-Правило-одного-определения-one-definition-rule) ещё почитайте.

Comment: @Денис: Для того, чтобы компилятор мог встроить функцию в месте вызова, он должен видеть ее исходный текст. Именно поэтому вы должны включать этот исходный текст во все cpp файлы через заголовочный файл. Если же вы "спрячете" определение своей функции в сpp файл, то во всех остальных файлах будет ошибка линкера.